# How to re-write the question in constructive way?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, capital-t-truth

I recently posted the following question: [Is there any islamic justification for killing the other Muslims with different Sharia'?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21457/is-there-any-islamic-justification-for-killing-the-other-muslims-with-different)

It was initially put on hold with the given reason being that it appeared to "[instigate argument and debate.](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21457/is-there-any-islamic-justification-for-killing-the-other-muslims-with-different#comment37304_21457)" I reformatted it completely, it is marked 3 times for reopen, but still on hold for being "[a Truth question that'll attract argument and debate](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21457/is-there-any-islamic-justification-for-killing-the-other-muslims-with-different#comment37334_21457)".

Do you see any specific problem with the question? If so, do you have any suggestion how to reformat it? (Please provide a very specific answer, not something general).